# Strange differences in website appearance over multiple computers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have been creating a website by modifying a WordPress, and I have found that when I view the page, some things function differently. For example, I have a banner that moves in and out depending on the scroll position (using jQuery Waypoints). On the computer I'm editing on, using the site in incognito doesn't load the font that overlays the banner. However, the font loads with another computer (same browser, different OS if that's helpful). Why do these things occur and how can I fix them?

By the way, the website is `tedxyouthhillsborough.com`.

Here's my code **(php)**:

```
<a href="/event-details/" class="bannerNav" style="margin-right: 0px;"><h2>
  <div style="margin-right: 0px;"><br/>SATURDAY MAY 24TH 2014<br/></div></h2>         <h3><div style="margin-right: 0px;"><br/>THE NUEVA SCHOOL<br/></div></h3></a>
```

Here's my **css:**

```
h2 div {
    font-family:'Open Sans', Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:83px;
    font-weight: 200;
}
h3 div {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    padding: 10px;
    color:rgb(114, 114, 114);
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right:120px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('a.logo_sm').fadeTo(0, 0);
 $('a.bannerNav').animate({
     'margin-right': '0px'
 })
 $('h3 div').animate({
     'margin-right': '0px'
 }, 200);
 $('h2 div').animate({
     'margin-right': '0px'
 }, 200);
 //$('.mainHeader').html(showFlag);

 $('div#main').waypoint(function (event, direction) {
     if (direction === 'down') {
         $('a.logo_sm').fadeTo(400, 1);
         $('a.flagNav').animate({
             'margin-left': '0px'
         }, 400);
         $('a.bannerNav').animate({
             'margin-right': '-352px'
         }, 200);
         $('h3 div').animate({
             'margin-right': '-352px'
         }, 200);
         $('h2 div').animate({
             'margin-right': '-352px'
         }, 200);
     } else {
         $('a.bannerNav').animate({
             'margin-right': '0px'
         }, 200);
         $('a.logo_sm').fadeTo(200, 0);
         $('a.flagNav').animate({
             'margin-left': '-195px'
         }, 400);
         $('h3 div').animate({
             'margin-right': '0px'
         }, 200);
         $('h2 div').animate({
             'margin-right': '0px'
         }, 200);
     }
 });

 });
```

Comment: Win7 Chrome (not incognito mode) - works fine here. `THE NUEVA SCHOOL` appears. I notice your css uses different capitalization - `Sans Serif` vs `sans serif`, but more particularly (especially in light of your mention of incognito mode) the mention of `Open Sans` - I'm not familiar enough with downloaded fonts for web-use. Without a specified full-path or url, I wonder if this CSS is relying on another page having previously used the `Open Sans` family. If this was the case, it may explain why it fails in incognito mode. Especially if it works in 'normal mode' on your pc.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, instead of using pixels (px), the use of em for sizing has far greater advantages such as greater responsiveness.  By the way I like the site, especially the theme.